# How can I prevent changing lock_escalation is SQL Server to take a long time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

I'm in a situation where I have a local development SQL Server and a production SQL Server.

I just discovered that there is a difference between a table.

The production SQL Server has:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO)
```

while my development SQL Server does not have this.

I want to remove this setting from the production server like so:

```
ALTER TABLE [Producten].[Producten] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
```

Unfortunately this is taking ages and I don't know why.

Maybe restarting the server may help but I don't want to restart the server without a good reason.

Any suggestions?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe the command is waiting that there are no locks on the table. If you are working on a production server this is a problem because there are clients working and setting locks on the table.

Comment: The command taking a long time aside, do you understand the implications of setting that on your production server? Specifically, is this table partitioned and do you want to avoid locks escalating to partition locks for some reason? If you need it, fair enough, but this has a bit of a smell of "reconcile all the differences".